# Conduction shape factors - textbooks inconsistent

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm working through a energy flow problem, and need to use the conduction shape factor for 'Row of N long cylinders against planar surface'. However two different texts give two different formulas for the shape factor.

from

http://www.mhhe.com/engcs/mech/holman/graphics/samplech_3.pdf page 8,

S=  2πL/[ln(2a/πD) x sinh(2πz/a)]

while a different textbook,

http://webserver.dmt.upm.es/~isidoro/bk3/c11/Heat%20conduction.pdf page 5,

S=  2πL**N**/[ln(2a/πD) x sinh(2πz/a)]

S is shape factor
L is length of the cylinders
**N is the number of cylinders**
a is spacing between cylinders
D is diameter of cylinders
z is depth below the surface

Only the second reference has the N term in the equation. Which equation should I be using?